# Perl JSON to_json not working after Ubuntu upgrade (14.04 -> 16.04)

Tags: json, perl

**Update**: A fresh install did not have the problem. I gave up on trying to fix the upgraded Ubuntu.

**Orignal question:**

I'm using the perl CPAN package JSON to convert a hasref to json using the  `to_json` function.

This worked fine on Ubuntu 14.04 with perl version 5.18.2, but after ugrading to Ubuntu 16.04 with perl version 5.22.1 I get the error message:

```
hash- or arrayref expected (not a simple scalar, use allow_nonref to allow this)
```

The orignal code was this:

```
my $lang = {
        'connection_lost' => 'Network connection was lost',
        'connection_lost_more' => 'Please refresh this page to fix this problem'
};
my $json_lang = to_json($lang);
```

I checked with `warn ref($lang)` the type of `$lang` which returned 'HASH', so it should be an hashref?

I tried to change it to this:

```
my %lang;
$lang{'connection_lost'} = 'Network connection was lost';
$lang{'connection_lost_more'} = 'Please refresh this page to fix this problem';
my $json_lang = to_json(%lang);
```

and this:

```
my %lang;
$lang{'connection_lost'} = 'Network connection was lost';
$lang{'connection_lost_more'} = 'Please refresh this page to fix this problem';
my $json_lang = to_json(\%lang);
```

Both failed.
Then I tried the `allow_nonref` switch:

```
my $lang = {
        'connection_lost' => 'Network connection was lost',
        'connection_lost_more' => 'Please refresh this page to fix this problem'
};
my $jsonnonref = JSON->new->allow_nonref; 
my $json_lang = $jsonnonref->to_json($lang);
```

which resulted in the error message `to_json should not be called as a method`

How do I get this to work?

Absolute minimal code that does not work for me:

```
package Handlers::test_handlers;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Apache2::Const -compile => qw(OK);
use Apache2::Request;

use JSON;

sub handler {
        my $lang = {
                'connection_lost' => 'connection_lost',
                'connection_lost_more' => 'connection_lost_more'
        };
        #my $json_lang = 'Hello world';
        my $json_lang = to_json($lang);        
        print $json_lang;
        return Apache2::Const::OK;
}

1;
```

Using the 'Hello world'-line works, while the to_json-line does not.

Comment: I just tried your original code on Perl 5.22 on Xenial and it works fine. I think you need to show us more of your code.

Comment: I think that at some point in time, `JSON` switched to using `JSON::XS` or `JSON::PP` (in order of preference). Maybe when that happened, the semantics of it changed slightly.

Comment: I added a `handler();` line at the end and installed libapache2-request-perl and libapache2-mod-perl2 and it works fine. Are you using the system Perl and modules or something like Perlbrew to manage the environment?

Comment: Apart from libapache2-request-perl and libapache2-mod-perl2 I have not installed any custom perl packages. JSON is installed via CPAN

Comment: Is there a reason why you installed JSON through CPAN instead of just using libjson-perl? Did you update your CPAN modules after the distro update completed?

Comment: Not really. The person I inherited the projet from said to install some packages via apt-get and some via CPAN. After upgrading I used apt-get update/upgrade and even "reinstalled" all packages (apt-get & CPAN). I now manually deleted all JSON files and installed it via apt-get. Still not working, with the same error.

Comment: Are you positive that this example: `my $json_lang = to_json(\%lang);` failed?

Comment: Just retried all my tests above with the non-CPAN JSON, still does not work. I guess I have to do a fresh 16.04 install, transfer my code and see if that works …

Comment: Please provide the output of `perl -E'use JSON; eval { require JSON::XS }; eval { require JSON::PP }; say "<$_>" for $JSON::VERSION, $JSON::XS::VERSION, $JSON::PP::VERSION, $INC{"JSON.pm"}, JSON->backend, to_json({a=>"b",c=>"d"})'`

Comment: @ikegami: <2.90>
<3.01>
<2.27202>
</usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/JSON.pm>
<JSON::XS>
<{"c":"d","a":"b"}>

Comment: Huh? You just showed `to_json` working for the same data you previously said it didn't work. Did you use a different `perl` this time?

Comment: No … the output is the same for sudo an non-sudo btw.

Comment: Well, you used *something* different, because `to_json` worked.

Comment: My first tests with a fresh 16.04 install seems promising. Did not install any json via CPAN, only via apt-get. Until now I found no places where any to_json or from_json calls broke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now had the same issue with a fresh install, and decided to completely remove JSON::XS / libjson-xs-perl from the project, which instantaneously fixed this problem